# Error message in align environment not showing line number

Tags: align, debugging

Is it possible to get more specific information such as the line number in case of an error in an align* environment? It is very annoying if you have to manually pinpoint an error in a 10 line align* environment. Would it at least be possible to obtain the line number of the error?

Regards,
Jens

Comment: No, that is not possible.  Errors are only reported once `\halign` has been processed completely, i.e. any error will always point to a line after it.  That is a core limitation of TeX itself.

Comment: @HenriMenke it's more a limitation of `align` than of tex. `tabular` for example also uses `\halign` but errors are reported earlier, the problem is that `align` is like `tabularx` not like `tabular` and grans the whole environment first before starting the alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeX (mostly) reports the line number of the point it has reached in the file, ad the body of an `align`, even though it uses environment syntax is read as a macro argument, and the whole environment is read before processing of the alignment is started.

You see similar effects in `tabularx` or any command with an explicit argument, such as `\parbox`.